# Emulating a processor's (limited) resources, including clock speed

Tags: performance, emulation, virtual-machine, qemu

I would like a software environment in which I can test the speed of my software on hardware with specific resources.  For example, how fast does this program run on an 800MHz x86 with 24 Mb of RAM, when my host hardware is a 3GHz quad core amd64 with 12GB of RAM?  Emulators such as qemu make a great point of running "almost as fast" as the underlying hardware; I would like to make it run slower.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure about processor speed, but you can definitely control RAM using a VM like VirtualBox, Parallels Desktop, etc.

Comment: Yes, I think memory is not the problem; the problem is speed and other resources.  I'm being inclusive in the phrasing because I want it to be just like the actual hardware, in every respect.  I was sort of hoping there was a ready-to-go solution, but evidently there isn't, so I'll take it piece by piece.

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried it, but perhaps you could achieve what you want to some extent by combining an emulator like QEMU or VirtualBox on Linux with something like this:

http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/

If you can limit the CPU time available to the emulator you might be able to simulate the results of execution on a slower computer. Keep in mind, though, that this would only affect the execution speed (or so I hope, anyway).

The CPU instruction set and other system features would remain unchanged. This means that emulating a *specific* processor accurately would be difficult if not impossible.

In addition, using something like cpulimit, which works using SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to repeatedly stop/restart the emulator process might cause side-effects, such as timing inconsistencies, video display artifacts etc.

Comment: This is interesting; I did not know about cpulimit.  While it isn't a complete solution, it is the most important "missing piece" of what I'm looking for, because I think that memory limits can already be set in most emulators.  I do realize that I wouldn't actually be emulating the other processor (unless qemu specifically emulates, say, a specific member of the x86 family), but this is probably close enough for my purposes.

Comment: *cpulimit* works quite well. OK the guest OS still print the physical cpu speed, but the available speed is set by cpulimit. e.g. `cpulimit -l 5 -s qemu-system-i386 -cpu pentium -m 32 <iso>` does emulate a Pentium 166MHz quite realistically. Thanks @thkala.

Answer (score 0):

In your emulator, keep a virtual "clock" and increment it appropriately as you execute each instruction. From there you can simply report how long it took in virtual time to execute, or you can have your emulator sleep now and again to keep execution speed roughly where it would be in the target.

Comment: This sounds hard.  I'm not sure whether this would be implemented in the host or guest OS, but I don't think I have the skills to do that either way.

Comment: @Liam: Also, you would not get a "feel" of how slow or fast it is, which would be important if you are evaluating e.g. a desktop application or other interactive software. Multimedia applications would be difficult to test, as well.